# Client - Server Chat in Twisted, Python

Tags: python, twisted

I can't get the Server and Client to communicate when they are both in different terminal windows. I can get them to both connect though not actually send their output to each others windows.I
Client:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, stdio, protocol

from twisted.protocols import basic


class Echo(basic.LineReceiver):

   def connectionMade(self):

       print "Welcome to the Chat, you have now connected"


  def lineReceived(self, line):

       self.sendLine(line)

       if line=="exit":

           connectionLost()



  def connectionLost(self):

       self.transport.loseConnection()


class EchoClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):

    protocol = Echo


factory = EchoClientFactory()

reactor.connectTCP("localhost", ...., factory)

reactor.run()
```

Server:

```
 from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, stdio

 from twisted.protocols import basic


 class Echo(basic.LineReceiver):

     print "Welcome to Chat"

     def connectionMade(self):

          print "A new client has connected"

     def lineReceived(self, line):

          self.sendLine(line)

          if line=="exit":

             connectionLost()


    def connectionLost(self):

       self.transport.loseConnection()



 class EchoServerFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):

    protocol = Echo


 factory = EchoServerFactory()

 reactor.listenTCP(...., factory)

 reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 3):

It is vital that you always post the exact code that you are running - your Echo Server specifies `....` as the port which raises a syntax error on execution. Posting the exact code will mean you get better responses faster.

Replacing the port with a number, `9999` say allows the server code to run. Now we can connect via telnet or netcat to test the server:

```
$ nc -c localhost 9999
hello
hello
```

Great! The server works fine. Note that it gives an error when you type "exit":

```
exceptions.NameError: global name 'loseConnection' is not defined
```

You should be calling `self.transport.loseConnection()` if you want to drop the connection manually. The `connectionLost` method you've defined is then called as an event to allow you to respond. You don't really need to define that method at this stage. Here is a modified version of your server code with the changes suggested:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, stdio
from twisted.protocols import basic

class Echo(basic.LineReceiver):
    print "Welcome to Chat"

    def connectionMade(self):
        print "A new client has connected"

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print 'server received:', line
        print 'server sent:', line, '\n'
        self.sendLine(line)
        if line=="exit":
             self.transport.loseConnection()


class EchoServerFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):
   protocol = Echo


factory = EchoServerFactory()
reactor.listenTCP(9999, factory)
reactor.run()
```

The client has the same problem with the port, changing to 9999 allows it to run. Your client connects, but then does not send any data. Here's a version that sends some text when it connects and echos text back to the server after a 2 second delay:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, stdio, protocol
from twisted.protocols import basic

class Echo(basic.LineReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "Welcome to the Chat, you have now connected"

        # send some text when we connect
        self.sendLine('hello')

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print 'client received:', line

        if len(line) > 10:
            self.sendLine('exit')
        else:
            # send a response in 2 seconds
            reactor.callLater(2, self.sendLine, '>' + line)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        reactor.stop()


class EchoClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = Echo

factory = EchoClientFactory()
reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 9999, factory)
reactor.run()
```

This causes the original message to bounce back and forwards to the server, while the client prepends a `>` character each time. The client will then send "exit" when the message gets to a certain length, causing the connection to be dropped by the server. When the connection is dropped, the client can stop its reactor so that it exits.

Typing into the terminal window does not send data through your client to the server - use telnet or netcat for this purpose.

Comment: Your code didn't work, all I want is to make them chat to each other, twisted is so confusing.

Comment: What is the purpose of: sendLine() and self.transport.write? They both seem like they transport data, yet in reality actually just print to the terminal window. And whats the difference between dataRecieved and lineRecieved they both seemd to do exactly the same thing. I tried rector.callLater from your code and it didn't work. This is really frustrating, the more I learn about twisted the more confusing it gets plus the community is dead so this ridiculously small problem has taken me ages. I can write server-client without twisted but I just want to learn it. Errrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr......

Comment: @mateus The LineReceiver class extends the base Protocol class and defines `sendLine` as a convenience method - it is probably something like `self.transport.write(line + '\n')`. It also defines `lineReceived` that gets called only when a complete line has been received, while the base `Protocol` class has `dataReceived` which is called when you might only have partial lines (eg only a few characters). You can't overwrite `dataReceived` in your `LineReceiver` class if you still want `lineReceived` to be called.

Comment: @mateus what exactly doesn't work for you and what were you expecting to happen - it works here

Comment: @mateus, oh are you expecting Chat functionality? `sendLine` and `self.transport.write` only send data back to the client of that connection. Take a look at http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/#auto1 if you want to send messages to other clients

Comment: @mateus Your client also doesn't allow users to type in messages - to acheive this you would have to read from stdin and write to the transport (or just use telnet)